# html5 remove from canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

This is my first html5 project, getting the gist of it, need a bit of help. I used a jquery UI slider to send an opacity value to the canvas and it works quite nicely... but I can't get the image to completely turn off when the slider is in the off position with a value of zero. Here is a fiddle of what I'm trying to do : http://jsfiddle.net/N6wZZ/2/

Here is my JS:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    animate: true,
    range: "min",
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 0.9,
    step: .01,
    create: function (event, ui) { 
        var opacityValue = '0.0';
        canvasFunction(opacityValue);
    },
    slide: function (event, ui) { 
         $('#hiddenField').attr('value', ui.value);
         $("#slider-result").html(ui.value);
         var opacityValue = $('#hiddenField').val();
         if (opacityValue == 0) {
            var opacityValue = 0;
            var workAroundVar = 300;
            var workAroundVarTwo = 0;
            canvasFunction(opacityValue, workAroundVar, workAroundVarTwo);
        } 
        else {
            var workAroundVar = 0;
            var workAroundVarTwo = 300;
            canvasFunction(opacityValue, workAroundVar, workAroundVarTwo);
        }
    }     
});
function canvasFunction(opacityValue, workAroundVar, workAroundVarTwo){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img1 = loadImage('http://moosepic.com/test2.png', main);
    var img2 = loadImage('http://moosepic.com/test.png', main);


    var imagesLoaded = 0;

    function main() {
      imagesLoaded += 1;

      if (imagesLoaded == 2) {
        // composite now
        ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, 300, 300);

          ctx.globalAlpha = opacityValue;
          ctx.drawImage(img2, workAroundVar, workAroundVar, workAroundVarTwo, workAroundVarTwo);

      }
    }

    function loadImage(src, onload) {
      var img = new Image();

      img.onload = onload;
      img.src = src;

      return img;
    }

}
```

as you can see I've made a bunch of workarounds to turn off the second image or just knock it out of the canvas. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: When you're drawing the canvas the very first time, what are workAroundVar 1 and 2 set to? I see them blank.

Comment: this is happening because your code's overall logic is wrong. do not load the images every time the slider moves, load them once and then just redraw the canvas. get rid of your workaround variables. they are wrong too.

Comment: @akonsu But loading the image is redraw right?

Comment: I am not sure that the browser (at least not all of them) would call the onload event handler for images that have been already loaded and are in the browser's cache.

Comment: Correct, but recently I did a lot of pixel level stuff on the canvas, and from my research I found out whenever I apply a pixel level operation, I have to apply the effect on the canvas and redraw the image on the canvas! I have posted a few questions here on SO too, you can check them out from my profile.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde I made the workAroundVar to try to kill the the second image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silas. I've taken a look at your jsFiddle. I forked it and made some changes/improvements to your approach and I think it accomplishes your goal:

http://jsfiddle.net/3LJsX/7/

Here is the approach I took (which is pretty close to yours, just some minor differences):

1. Load our first image
2. Load our second image in the onLoad function of the first image
3. Create our slider in the onLoad function of the second image
4. The slider's create and update methods both call the `refreshVisuals` function which updates the value of the slider div and updates the canvas

A main difference is in the `draw` function which was called `canvasFunction` in your example. In my `draw` function, I make sure to:

1. Clear the canvas each time we draw
2. Make sure the alpha is at 1 when we draw our first image with the tree
3. Draw the tree image
4. Update the alpha to be whatever the current value is for the slider
5. Draw our tiedie image

That should be it! Let me know if you have any questions.